# Stars moving in a straight line in Minnesota

Tags: satellite, identify-this-object

I was outside at around 7:50 to 8:09 ish. At I looked up in the sky to see around 20-50 stars or something moving in a straight line at the same speed. I have never seen anything like this ever. And they keep appearing out of nowhere. Felt like I was at a firework show except no explosions and cool lights. Kinda freaky if you ask me

Comment: This will be happening regularly from now on!

Comment: Starlink satellites. Blame Elon.

Comment: Could someone's military start shooting those bloody things down, pleasseee. :-)